# Load url with parameters via ajax in jQuery Mobile

Tags: ajax, jquery, parameters, jquery-mobile

### Problem

I cannot load linked pages with parameters via Ajax in jQuery mobile.
Like: `http://www.sampleurl.com/tool.dll?name=first&more=parameters`

### Details

I'm using jQuery Mobile **1.0b3**

I don't refer to in-page navigation with hashtags. I intend to load another webpage (separate html file). So as far as I know there shouldn't be a problem with JQM searching the linked website within the current page.

In some cases I have to reference a DLL which is returning the HTML document as response.
Unfortunately I cannot access these pages with jQuery Mobile using Ajax.

To give an example: I am on the following website
`http://www.sampleurl.com/tool.dll?name=first&more=parameters`

and I want to access another website like this:

```html
<a href="/tool.dll?name=second&more=parameters"> Link </a>
```

This is not working with Ajax enabled. I have to force non-ajax with the attribute `rel="external"`.
Is it not possible to access liks with parameters in JQM this way? I'd like to use the built-in loading notification for pages. What am I missing?

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution in similiar questions.

### Code samples

```html
<!-- This is working, but will not get me a loading notification on mobile devices -->
<a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="/tool.dll?name=this%20one&more=parameters">
    Link
</a>

<!-- This is not working -->
<a href="/tool.dll?&name=second&more=parameters">
    Link
</a>

<!-- Neither is this working -->
<a href="http://www.sampleurl.com/tool.dll?name=this%20one&more=parameters">
    Link
</a>
```

### New insights (edit)

For some reason JQM is stuck at loading the page because of this line within the website:

```html
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="" />
```

The issue is the attribute `type="date"`! With an text-field the page loads fine via ajax.

The page itself is working fine with jQuery Mobile. The date-input just prevents the page from loading via ajax.
I haven't found a solution for this problem, yet. The empty value attribute is not the problem.

Comment: I never had problems with that sinde alpha2, except the cases in which the part of the link before `?` was incorrect. Could you post a link to a working example? If you do so - write a comment and I'll try to debug it.

Comment: @naugtur The link is working, when I declare it as external via `rel="external"` and therefore disable the use of ajax. The link is correct, but I cannot provide a working link since it's target is an internal development system.

Comment: In addition: I checked the network tab of firebug. JQM is requesting the page correctly and getting the correct website as response. The problem is that JQM keep hanging at "loading" and is not showing the loaded page. The page itself is valid and working fine on its own.

Comment: I added new insights on my problem. The date-input field is causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

This issue is not related to GET parameters and the ajax request.
The problem is caused by the datepicker plugin for jQuery Mobile, when included in the landing page.

If you have to include the script always, you will need to disabled the use of ajax via:
`rel="external" data-ajax="false"`

### Solution

#### Landing page

```
<!-- Do not include the datepicker script in the landing page -->
<div data-role="page" id="pg_1"> 
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Ajax page test with date input field</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content_div" data-role="content">
        <p>
            <a data-role="button" href="loadme.html">To the calendar</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Calendar page

```
<head>
    <!-- include datepicker only on the target page -->
    <!-- renamed and modified version of the datepicker experiment from JQM -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile-calendar.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="pg_2"> 
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Ajax page test with date input field</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="content_div" data-role="content">
            <p>
                <input type="date" name="date" value="" />
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html">Back</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's a serious bug in JQM calendar. Thanks for posting your findings!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can but into 2 steps:
First by dividing your url into two parts first till and before the ? and the other part which is the data which comes after the ? and to do this you have to use javascript reg-expression, do some research.
Second using ajax in jquery mobile in the url (attribute) part you will put the first part you got it using javascript reg-expression and the second part in the data (attribute) part

Comment: Interesting solution. I'll check this out, when I have some time to implement it and report back afterwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with $.mobile.loadPage?

you can find the documentation about this method here

[jquerymobile api methods $.mobile.loadPage](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/methods.html)

so, you can try to do somethig like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadNewContain();"> Link </a>

<script>
function loadNewContain()
{
$.mobile.loadPage('http://www.sampleurl.com/tool.dll?&name=first&more=parameters');
}
</script>
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion this method, but unfortunately this isn't working either. The script gets executed and contains a working url, but as before the page is not loaded-, even if I overwrite the default values of `loadPage`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
<a href="/tool.dll?name=second&more=parameters"> Link </a>
```

Without the ?&... that should do the trick.  HTML doesn't recognize ?& as a valid parameter.

Comment: No offense, but `...?key=value&key2=value2` ist the standard GET parameter format for the query string. `?&...` is a typo.